# Добавить автоинкримент в существующую таблицу по дате

Tags: sql-server

В таблице с данными info есть поле date.

Пытаюсь добавить поле id с автоинкриментом `ALTER TABLE info ADD id INT IDENTITY(1,1)`, но при сортировке по id даты идут вразнобой.

Как привязать получение автоинкримента к дате?

Comment: Только без автоинкремента самому назначить id. И по хорошему id и даты никак не должны быть связаны. вот выдали мы id 1,2,3 а потом вставляем запись с датой где то посередине между теми что в записях 2 и 3, и какой id такой записи давать 2.5 ?

Comment: Даты одноразово пишутся, потом не меняются и идут на увеличение.
Можно было бы и ручками, но как то желания нет пару сотен тысяч записей править:)

Comment: ну ручками то их править проще простого `with q as(select id,row_number() over(order by DATE_FIELD) new from info)
update q set id=new` но колонка должна быть не identity, так что дальше будете вести ее значение триггерами или еще как нибудь

Comment: Спасибо!:) Получилось.
Нашел еще неплохой вариант:
`CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX X_sort ON info (date ASC)
ALTER TABLE info ADD id INT IDENTITY(1,1)
DROP INDEX X_sort ON info`

Comment: @Art, тогда разместите, пожалуйста, найденное решение как ответ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1 вариант:**

```
ALTER TABLE info ADD id int NULL

with q as (
    select id, row_number() over (order by date) new from info
)
update q set id = new
```

В свойствах поля id включаем спецификацию идентификатора 1,1 и делаем NOT NULL

**2 вариант (оптимальней):**

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX X_sort ON info (date ASC)
ALTER TABLE info ADD id INT IDENTITY(1,1)
DROP INDEX X_sort ON info
```